# 2.7.0 Update Error

Tags: updating, update

I'm trying to update to 2.7.0 from 2.6.1.

I've done this on one website we have, but the other just isn't playing...

I'm doing the exact same thing (And also tried this 3 times and still getting the same issue) It gets to the point where I agree to the terms & conditions, then goes to this URL:

http://website.com/admin.php?C=wizard&M=do_update&language=english&ajax_progress=yes

And displays a Google Chrome error:

Server error

I normally see these errors when there is a missing DB file, or an error with the DB. But I've restored it back, ensured the CMS worked, then tried again and it still doesn't do it.

Console isn't showing anything neither.

What could be causing this?

---

Edit (After Disabling JS)

http://website.com/admin.php?C=wizard&M=do_update&language=english

---

Edit (PHP Error)

[04-Sep-2013 12:13:21 Europe/Dublin] PHP Fatal error:  Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in /Users/shape2/repositories/website.com/system/expressionengine/third_party/pt_field_pack/pt_fieldtype.php on line 148

Comment: this was an error that seemed to be around a while back. IIRC the fix then was to disable JS and try it that way. I think Firefox handled it better than Chrome did.

Comment: @StevenGrant Disable JS in the browser?

Comment: @StevenGrant Just disabled JS and it results with a new URL (In original question)

Comment: yeah, did you try it in Firefox?

Comment: @StevenGrant Yeah I tried it in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. All white / Error screens.

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your PHP error logs?

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl There is only 1 PHP error showing up, which i've added to the original question. This PHP Error was also showing up for the previous site I upgraded, but that went through fine.

Comment: I'd personally wait a couple more weeks to upgrade. Not all the major addons are updated to work with V2.7 yet.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl Yeah - I placed the "third_party" add-ons in after the update and this worked. I also tried removing field pack and that worked also. Would this cause any problems? I've found most of the add-ons i'm using have got updates for 2.7.0 so I'm safe :)

Comment: Shouldn't cause a problem. Keep an eye on things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same error going from 2.6.1 to 2.7.0. Here's how I got around it.

Don't upload your system -> third party folders until after you run the installer.

I followed all the steps here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html
except for uploading the add-ons to third party at the end of #3, ran the update and everything was fine. Then afterwards I uploaded the add-ons and everything was still okay.

It looks like conflict for you is on the add-on with the folder 'pt_field_pack'. For me it was a plugin called Safecracker Registration. You could optionally just take out the 'pt_field_pack' folder before running the install too.

Also, if afterwards in case you get an error in your control panel that says '*Your ExpressionEngine installation’s version (2.6.1) is not consistent with the reported version (2.7.0). Please update your installation of ExpressionEngine again.*' refer to this thread: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237540/ and open system/installer/updates/ud_270.php and ADD this code ABOVE line 1050:

```
    if (empty($data))
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted... Because it worked and so do all the add-ons even when I place them in the 'third_party' folder - After the update. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

> [04-Sep-2013 12:13:21 Europe/Dublin] PHP Fatal error: Class PT_Fieldtype contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (EE_Fieldtype::display_field) in /Users/shape2/repositories/website.com/system/expressionengine/third_party/pt_field_pack/pt_fieldtype.php on line 148

Have you updated "pt field pack" with new "Field Pack" as well?

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack